# Image preloader javascript that supports events

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, preloader, preloading

I am trying to find an image preloader script.

While i found a few, none of them supports an event that is triggered when preloading is finished.

Does anyone know of any script or jQuery plugin that will do this?

Hope this question is appropriate for stackoverflow - if not, feel free to remove it in an instant.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here's a function that will preload images from an array and call your callback when the last one has finished:

```
function preloadImages(srcs, imgs, callback) {
    var img;
    var remaining = srcs.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < srcs.length; i++) {
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            --remaining;
            if (remaining <= 0) {
                callback();
            }
        };
        img.src = srcs[i];
        imgs.push(img);
    }
}

// then to call it, you would use this
var imageSrcs = ["src1", "src2", "src3", "src4"];
var images = [];

preloadImages(imageSrcs, images, myFunction);
```

---

And since we're now in the age of using promises for asynchronous operations, here's a version of the above that uses promises and notifies the caller via an ES6 standard promise:

```
function preloadImages(srcs) {
    function loadImage(src) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function() {
                resolve(img);
            };
            img.onerror = img.onabort = function() {
                reject(src);
            };
            img.src = src;
        });
    }
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < srcs.length; i++) {
        promises.push(loadImage(srcs[i]));
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
}

preloadImages(["src1", "src2", "src3", "src4"]).then(function(imgs) {
    // all images are loaded now and in the array imgs
}, function(errImg) {
    // at least one image failed to load
});
```

---

And, here's a version using 2015 jQuery promises:

```
function preloadImages(srcs) {
    function loadImage(src) {
        return new $.Deferred(function(def) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function() {
                def.resolve(img);
            };
            img.onerror = img.onabort = function() {
                def.reject(src);
            };
            img.src = src;
        }).promise();
    }
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < srcs.length; i++) {
        promises.push(loadImage(srcs[i]));
    }
    return $.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
        // return results as a simple array rather than as separate arguments
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    });
}

preloadImages(["src1", "src2", "src3", "src4"]).then(function(imgs) {
    // all images are loaded now and in the array imgs
}, function(errImg) {
    // at least one image failed to load
});
```

Comment: For completeness on this function, you could add onerror handlers, onabort handlers and a timeout such that you could still call your callback if one or more of the images had a problem loading and would never complete successfully.  It will work fine as is if the images don't have errors loading.

Comment: Yes, that is quite nice. I was trying to show that,  but I fell short.

Comment: Added versions of the `preloadImages()` function that use promises, both standard ES6 promises and jQuery promises.

Comment: It seems to me that new additions are missing img.src = src; after var img = new Image();

Answer (score 2):

For a more robust solution, consider this `PRELOADER` function with a couple of callbacks ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wkmrY/)).

### Keeping it simple:

In this example, I'm passing callbacks and an image hash inside an `Object` literal `PRELOADER_OBJECT`, then overriding the callbacks inside `PRELOADER`:

```
// preloder object stores image hash
// and event handler callbacks
var PRELOADER_OBJECT = {

    imgArray:"http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg http://torwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/chewbacca-w-han-solo-anh.jpg".split(" "),

    progressCallback : function( percent )
    {
        $( '#preloader_progress' ).html( 'preload progress complete : ' + percent + '%' );
        console.log( 'preload progress complete : ', percent );
    },

    completeCallback : function( scope )
    {
        // hide preload indicator, do something when finished
        console.log( 'preload complete!' );
        $( '#preloader_modal' ).delay( 1000 ).animate( { opacity : 0 }, function( )
        {
            $( '.preload_class' ).each( function( index )
            {
                $( this ).delay( index * 100 ).animate( { opacity : 0 } );
            } );
        } );
    }

/*Localize params and create PRELOADER object. 
Needs to loadImages( ); iterate through hash and 
call onPreloadProgress( ) and onPreloadComplete( )
each time until finished. If you're still within
bounds of the image hash, call progressCallback( )
recursively. When finished, fire onCompleteCallback( )*/

var PRELOADER = function( object )
{
    // preloader modal overlay
    this.modal = undefined;

    // progress indicator container
    this.progressIndicator = undefined;

    // image preload progress
    this.progress = undefined;

    // progress callback
    this.progressCallback = undefined;

    // complete callback
    this.completeCallback = undefined;

    // hash to store key : value pairs for image paths
    this.imgArray = undefined; 

    // store images in preloadArray
    this.preloadArray = [];

    // initialize and localize our data
    this.initialize = function( )
    {
        // create preload indicator and overlay modal
        this.createPreloaderModal( );

        // image hash
        this.imgArray = object.imgArray;

        // progress callback event handler
        this.progressCallback = object.progressCallback;

        // complete callback event
        this.completeCallback = object.completeCallback;

        // load images
        this.loadImages( );
    };

    this.progressCallback = function( ) {}; // function to override

    this.completeCallback = function( ) {}; // function to override

    // load images into DOM and fire callbacks
    this.loadImages = function( )
    {
        var that = this;

        // iterate through hash and place images into DOM
        $.each( PRELOADER_OBJECT.imgArray, function( index, object )
        {
            this.image = $( "<img/>", { "src" : object, "class": "preload_class" } ).appendTo( 'body' );

            // mark progress and call progressCallback( ) event handler
            that.progress = Math.ceil( ( index / PRELOADER_OBJECT.imgArray.length ) * 100 );
            that.progressCallback( this.progress );

            that.preloadArray.push( this.image );
        } );

        // check for array bounds and call completeCallback( )
        if ( PRELOADER_OBJECT.imgArray.length )
        {
            this.progressCallback( 100 );
            this.completeCallback( this );
        }
    };

    // create modal to display preload data
    this.createPreloaderModal = function( )
    {
        this.modal = $( '<div/>', { 'id' : 'preloader_modal' } ).appendTo( 'body' );
        this.progressIndicator = $( '<h1/>', { 'id' : 'preloader_progress' } ).appendTo( this.modal );
    };
};

// trigger event chain when DOM loads
$( document ).ready( function( )
{    
    // instantiate PRELOADER instance and pass
    // our JSON data model as a parameter
    var preloader = new PRELOADER( PRELOADER_OBJECT );

    // initialize preloader
    preloader.initialize( );
} );
```

};​

With a site load large enough to require an image preloader, the modal text display could be easily modified to support a data-driven jQuery animation.

Answer (score 0):

Preloading and loading are the same thing. You can insert the image (either create a new one or change the "src" attribute of an existing one) but hide the element using `$("element").hide()` or something similar. Before you do this, attach a load event handler like so:

```
var images = ["src1", "src2", "src3", "src4"];
var len = images.length;

for(i=0; i<len; i++){
    $("parent element").html('<img id="new-img" style="display:none;" src="'+images[i]+'"/>');
    $("new-img").load(function(){
        //Your image is now "preloaded"

        //Now you can show the image, or do other stuff
        $(this).show();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank You, simon. I am trying to set this up for a contact map where there are parts of a country that are to be displayed, which are each PNGs, pretty huge. I want to preload the whole thing, then add a class name to its container to make it visible. That's pretty much all. But attaching a callback for triggering on load of a single image is not what i am looking for.

Comment: What do you mean by "pre-loading"? I assume you want to load it before the user needs it so that when he/she wants to see it, it doesn't take a millenium to show up. Use the above code to load the image, once it is loaded, you can store a reference to it so you can refer to it when the user needs to see it. This effectively pre-loads the image.

Comment: Thank you, i understand, but it is just not what i am looking for. I am trying to find a script that i can feed with an array of image sources, which loads them in the background and then triggers an event.

Comment: Every time an image is done loading, do a var++, and if the var == the number of images to preload, run your "everything loaded" routine

Answer (score 0):

Preloading takes some extra work like creating new image elements, monitoring if they are all loaded and then replacing them with the existing ones in the DOM. However you  may do this directly on the DOM `<img>` elements indefinitely many times without replacing them.

We may use the Fetch API to access the images, wait until they are all downloaded within a `promise.all()` and then in one go just replace the `src` attributes of the `img` elements at the most suitable time by using `window.requestAnimationFrame()`.

In the following example I refresh the `src` attributes of the `img` elements 10 times. As per the delay, i am using the the time it takes up to load 4 images from an API. So once we have all images loaded i am immediately placing a new request by calling the same `refreshImagesNTimes` function recursively.

You may of course chose to load as many image blobs as you like all at once and display them in groups in precise time intervals by using a simple `setTimeout` mechanism.

```js
function refreshImagesNTimes(nodeList,count = -1){
  var imgPromises = Array.from({length: nodeList.length})
                         .map(_ => fetch("https://unsplash.it/480/640/?random").then(res => res.blob()));
  Promise.all(imgPromises)
         .then(function(blobs){
                 window.requestAnimationFrame(_ => nodeList.forEach((img, i) => img.src = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blobs[i])));
                 --count && refreshImagesNTimes(nodeList, count);
               });
}

var images = document.querySelectorAll("#container img");
refreshImagesNTimes(images,10);
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 75vw;
  height: 56.25vw;
  background-color: #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  width: 45%;
  height: 45%;
  background-color: thistle;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img>
  <img>
  <img>
  <img>
</div>
```