# How can I call images into the DOM without querying the server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Given a number of images (animation frames) I would like to prefetch them and then show them on a webpage as needed.

I have tried several ways of prefetching, including [a nifty plugin](http://alz.so/imageloader/), but here's a dead simple method:

```
<div class="animation-container"></div>

<div class="holding-container" style="display:none"></div>

<script>
$('.holding-container').append('<img src="Image1.png" />');
$('.holding-container').append('<img src="Image2.png" />');
</script>
```

In the Network tab of Firebug or developer tools, I see these calls result in queries to the server, and the images are fetched successfully.

Now, I want to actually use the images. Here's some very simplified code:

```
$('.animation-container').prepend('<img src="Image1.png"/>');
```

**This is where things go off the rails.** The network tabs show the browsers query the server *again* (receiving 304 NOT MODIFIED). This results in about a 200ms delay before the image is shown. Why does this happen and what can I do about it?

Comment: You're creating a new Image element. Try transferring it from the `.holding-container` instead. It will be fastest if you keep a reference when you append it: `var img1 = $('<img src="Image1.png" />').appendTo(".holding-container");` Then do the prepend like this: `img1.prependTo('.animation-container')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new DOM object instead of re-using the one that was pre-fetched.

Add an id to each image to uniquely identify it -

```
<div class="animation-container"></div>
<div class="holding-container" style="display:none"></div>
<script>
    $('.holding-container').append('<img src="Image1.png" id="img1" />');
    $('.holding-container').append('<img src="Image2.png" id="img2" />');
</script>
```

And then to grab the element using a selector, `detach()` it (like `remove()` but keeps the info, you can omit this if you you want to keep it in your holding container), and `prependTo()` it to your container:

```
$('.holding-container #img1').detach().prependTo('.animation-container');
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe CSS sprites will help you. These are great for animation and if you're have not enough image editing skills, there are whole bunch free online generators.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways that you can preload images:

[Image preloader javascript that supports events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264528/image-preloader-javascript-that-supports-events/8265310#8265310)

[Is there a way to load images to user's cache asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450068/is-there-a-way-to-load-images-to-users-cache-asynchronously/8450190#8450190)

In both cases, these preload images into cached images.  Then, when you use those image URLs anywhere else in your web page, they will load immediately (from the browser cache).

Comment: Both of those are excellent prefetchers I'm sure, but they leave out a critical bit of information -- how do you actually use the images once they are fetched? Can they be called out of an object or does placing them into the DOM cause a server query (which returns 304 Not Modified, per my question above)?

Comment: @MartinBurch - After the images are preloaded, I was trying to explain that you just create an image object, assign the image URL as the image `src` and the image will load immediately from the browser cache (without calling the server).  That's what "preloading into the cache" means and does and that's how you use this code.