# Image not changing

Tags: javascript

Hi I am trying to get an image to blink using the code below by changing the image. Is there something wrong with my "setTimeout"? TIA

```
var Test = new Array();
Test.length = 2;

for (var i = 0; i < Test.length; i++) { 
    Test[i] = new Image();
    Test[i].src = "images/Image2" + (i+1) + ".png";
}

function ChangeImage() {
    for (var i = 0; i < Test.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById('Test_Image').src = Test[i].src; 
    }
    setTimeout("ChangeImage()", 1000);           
 }   

 ChangeImage();
```

Comment: I do not think `src` is being changed... Same `src` is being assigned again and again...

Comment: I believe your setTimeout should be `setTimeout(ChangeImage, 1000);` - no quotes, no `()`.

Comment: `setTimeout()` is not blocking so you schedule `Test.length` `setTimeout()` calls to all run at the exact same time.

Comment: I tried without quotes still nothing, what do you mean not blocking?

Comment: @user1342164 did you try without `()` as well? `setTimeout` should not include these, and if they're necessary, you must use an anonymous function.

Comment: I mean that `setTmeout()` just schedules an activity to run in the future and then the rest of your JS continues to run.  It doesn't "wait" until the `setTimeout()` fires before continuing with the rest of your `for` loop.

Comment: Your function doesn't make sense. You're always going to end up with the last src.

Comment: Like this? setTimeout "ChangeImage()", 1000;

Comment: No, I meant like my first comment. `setTimeout(ChangeImage, 1000);` - However, as other commenters have pointed out, I don't see how this function will work - are you trying to change the image once per second?

Comment: `setTimeout(ChangeImage, 1000);` This still won't work. You will only ever see the last src because of how fast the code runs.

Comment: Thanks Gavin, nothing happening still.

Comment: @user1342164 You're gonna need to outline what you *want* to happen, or what you mean by "blink". Your `ChangeImage` function updates the image src for each iteration of the `for` loop, which happens too fast to even be visible.

Comment: ok yes just want to image src to change like every couple seconds, can I change the timeout value?

Comment: @user1342164 you shouldn't use array constructor. It's prefered to use `[]` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First.. you complicated yourself with the new Image() part. You could just use Test[i] = "images/Image2" + (i+1) + ".png";

And for your code, firstly you change the images really fast once every 1 second.

It should be something like this:

```
function ChangeImage() {
    for (var i = 0; i < Test.length; i++) {
       setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('Test_Image').src = Test[i]; 
        }, (i+1) *1000);      
    }      

   if(play){
     setTimeout("ChangeImage()", Test.length * 1000);        
   }
}
```

This will not halt the javascript code at any point.

After 1 sec it will put image21, after 2 seconds image21 and it will call itself again and it will start all over again;

I put the variable play so you could stop the animation if you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

**Edit**: Accidentally put `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`. Thanks Santi for point that out.

```
var Test = new Array();
Test.length = 2;

for (var i = 0; i < Test.length; i++) { 
    Test[i] = new Image();
    Test[i].src = "images/Image2" + (i+1) + ".png";
}

var count = 0;

function ChangeImage() {
  if (count >= Test.length)
    count = 0;
  document.getElementById('Test_Image').src = Test[count].src;  
  count++;   
}   

setInterval(ChangeImage, 1000);
```

Comment: This will only happen once. Change the `setTimeout` to be a `setInterval` or put it within the `ChangeImage` function.

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout()` is not blocking.  That means it only schedules an activity to happen some time in the future and the rest of your Javascript just keeps running.  So, you were scheduling `Test.length` `setTimeout()` all for the exact same time 1 second from now.  Instead, you need to schedule the next image change and then, when that timer fires, you schedule the one after that and so on.

If you just want to cycle through the various images one second apart, you can do this:

```
function ChangeImage() {
    var cntr = 0;

    function next() {
        if (cntr < Test.length) {
            document.getElementById('Test_Image').src = Test[cntr++].src; 
            // after changing src, schedule next change for 1 second from now
            setTimeout(next, 1000);
        }
    }
    // start first iteration
    next();
 }   

 ChangeImage();
```

You may also need to make sure that all your images are properly preloaded so they display immediately when you set their source.  There are numerous ways to make sure the preload is done before starting the rotation such as these:

[Image preloader javascript that supports events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264528/image-preloader-javascript-that-supports-events/8265310#8265310)

[How do you cache an image in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240110/how-do-you-cache-an-image-in-javascript/10240297#10240297)

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop switches the src once and immediately switches it back, so you can't see it change. Try this instead:

```
var Test = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    Test.push("images/Image2" + (i+1) + ".png");
};

var x = 0;
document.getElementById('Test_Image').src = Test[x];

(function ChangeImage() {
    if(++x >= Test.length) x = 0;
    document.getElementById('Test_Image').src = Test[x];
    setTimeout(ChangeImage, 1000);
})();
```

EDIT: As Santi pointed out, my original solution only supported two images, while OP requested to loop through an array.

Comment: OP seemed to have laid out his solution to loop through an array very intentionally. Your solution works specifically for only two images.